# Is Hades ever associated with iron?

Tags: greek, passage-request, mythology

Traditionally, the Greek and Roman god of the dead is associated with gold and silver, since he controls everything under the earth: he has epithets like *Plūtōn* "the [god] of riches" and *Dīs Pater* "the wealthy father".

But does this extend to other metals? In particular, does any classical author specifically associate Hades with iron, bronze, or other useful (rather than ornamental) metals? Or are those the dominion of a different god? Greek and Latin answers are both acceptable.

(This question is inspired by the recent Broadway musical *Hadestown*, which calls the lord of the underworld "king of iron, king of steel".)

Comment: A guess: the application of "iron" & "steel" is to indicate strength/ power? The trick used by Stalin, adapting the Russian word for steel--maybe. Don't forget, old Hades was "malis avibus"--I like that expression!

Comment: FWIW, [Vulcan/Hephaestus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulcan_(mythology)) is the god of fire and smithery, and reportedly _came to be considered as the manufacturer of art, arms, [and...] **iron**_